# Heroku cannot find module 'spawn-sync'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to install my node project to run online however when i try to push to heroku master I get errors. 
I followed these steps: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#push-local-changes 
the first error is:

```
remote:        > node lib/install.js
remote:
remote:        module.js:338
remote:            throw err;
remote:                  ^
remote:        Error: Cannot find module 'spawn-sync'
remote:            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
remote:            at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
remote:            at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
remote:            at require (module.js:384:17)
remote:            at Object.<anonymous>        check/index.js:5:17)
```

I tried to install de module with `npm install spawn-sync --save` and runned `git add -A` and `git commit -m "added spawn-sync"` and again tried to `git push heroku master` but the error keeps coming up.
I'm working in a branch and i'm in the root folder of my application.
Does anyone know how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you're on the master branch. If you're not working on `master`, you should push to heroku like `git push heroku branchYouAreOn:master`.
2. Make sure `spawn-sync` is listed in `dependencies` in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped. But i had to use `sudo` to make it work. spawn-sync is in de dependencies, forgot to mention that in my question.